# Why the one site redirecting to another in NGINX

Tags: nginx, url, redirect

there was 2 sites in Nginx web server, i wanted to add another one.
1. i have downloaded new site's content
2. then create new config file in /etc/nginx/conf.d folder, like previous sites.

And add new site's name in DNS server, and now when i try to open new site from browser, i see content of my old sites, but URL is the new ones. Please help to troubleshoot

Comment: Provide minimal example.

Comment: Have site1.com site2.com, i have added site3.com, downloaded site.3com content, and created in /etc/nginx/conf.d "site3.com.conf" standart config file with standart "server {
    listen       80;

    server_name site.3.com www.site3.com;
    root /home/vhosting/site.com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
", and now when i type in browser site3.com it opening site2.com content. dont know why

Comment: Have you restarted nginx service or force it to reload configs?

Comment: after some checks, and sure reload/restart nginx, now if i tried to open site3.com facing php errors (its ok, i will check later), but when i tried httpS://site3.com, it will redirecting to site2.com

Comment: Https is listening on port 443 not 80. as you mentioned in comments, what you wrote.

Comment: so until i will config SSL for this new site (site3.com), in browser it ( httpS://site3.com) should open httpS://site2.com?

Comment: It will open default page. Notice if you have defaut.conf and in server_name default value.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem was only in https, and in main nginx.conf file there was server_name default value, which the reason why i saw another site content.